# Is it a best practice never to directly call std::allocator's member functions?

Tags: c++, memory-management, standards, type-traits, allocator

As far as I know, a standard-compliant container always uses

`std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>`

to perform allocate/deallocate/construct/destroy actions, instead of directly calling `allocator_type`'s member functions.

If it's true. `std::allocator<T>` is similar to an internal class of

`std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>`, then in what cases will

`std::std::allocator<T>::address(reference)` be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, in C++11 code. `std::allocator` is defined in C++98 to have a member function called `address`, so it has to keep it for backwards compatibility. C++98 doesn't have `allocator_traits`.

When the committee introduced `allocator_traits` for C++11, it initially had an `address` member, but was later removed by the adoption of [N2982](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2982.pdf). The relevant discussion in that paper says that "The functionality of `address` is now provided by the `pointer_to` function in `pointer_traits`."

Comment: +1. Thank you very much for your detailed information. My speculation is confirmed.